# how to understand telephony is Busy in Android?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I wrote application that used AlarmManager ,Its Work very well But when user Speaks with telephony,music is Playing in alarmManager,thus it's not good for User.

How to Disable AlarmManager when Telephony is Busy

Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

`TelephonyManager.getCallState()` tells you, if the user is using the phone right now:

```
private boolean isUserInCall(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getCallState() != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
}
```

Comment: what is value : TelephonyManagerCALL_STATE_IDLE